# Do Bazel genrules offer a temp directory?

Tags: bazel

Does Bazel offer a variable substitution for a temp directory in genrules?

Sometimes I need a staging area before creating the final output artefact.

I am imagining something like this:

```py
genrule(
    name = "example",
    srcs = [ "a.txt" ],
    cmd = "cp $< $(TMP)/b.txt && cp $(TMP)/b.txt $@",
)
```

`$(TMP)` would be a folder generated for me by Bazel on each rule execution.

Comment: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/10136

Answer (score 4):

No it doesn't. (As of Bazel 0.23.1)

It does set `$TMPDIR` though (even with [--incompatible_strict_action_env](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#flag--incompatible_strict_action_env)), so `mktemp` should work. But `$TMPDIR` is by no means a dedicated temp directory (it's often just `/tmp`), so be careful what you [clobber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clobbering).

Comment: I see. Would you be able to recommend a best-practice here?

Comment: Yes, albeit a complicated one: (1) wrap the entire cmd body in a shell function, and call it (2) create a temp directory as the first thing in the function, store its path in some variable (3) add a `trap` to clean up the temp directory.

Answer (score 2):

I migrated my genrule to a full Starlark rule. There I can do

```
tmp = ctx.actions.declare_directory("TMP_" + ctx.label.name)
```

and just use that directory as my temp in further actions.

It is similar to what the Starlark tutorial shows, in https://docs.bazel.build/versions/2.0.0/skylark/rules-tutorial.html#creating-a-file. The difference is that I do not register that directory as an output. That is, I *don't* do something like

```
return [DefaultInfo(files = depset([tmp]))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own inside the bash code:

```bash
export TMP=$(mktemp -d || mktemp -d -t bazel-tmp)

trap "rm -rf $TMP" EXIT # Delete on exit

# Do things...
```